# How does server 2016 core know it has to start cmd.exe as shell?

Tags: shell, windows-server-2016

Does anyone know how Server Core knows it has to start cmd.exe as shell?

It being just another version of Windows, you would expect it to be specified the same way as it always has from NT on, via one of these registry keys:

- HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon
- HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon
- Value Shell, REG_SZ = the executable to start as shell (full path if it isn't in C:\Windows).

However, that isn't what I found in Server 2016 Core. The Shell value doesn't exist in the HKCU branch, and in the HKLM branch it is set to "explorer.exe" like in a full GUI installation.

Knowing where to find it could allow someone to use another shell (powershell for instance), or let it open the sconfig menu by default instead of just an empty CMD window (meaning *instead of* the cmd window, instead of *besides* it as would be via the Run registry key).

Comment: With my limited knowledge of Windows, I find this a strange question.  I always thought cmd.exe was the Windows shell command.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Windows Core installations by default only start a console window and not a full blown Desktop experience with explorer.exe running etc.

Comment: A console "window"?  Or just a console?  Anyway, there's probably something running in that console, probably a shell, by default cmd.exe ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, just for clarity: the default shell for Windows is explorer.exe, the first instance of which that is started shows the GUI shell consisting of the desktop, start button and task bar. Server core uses cmd.exe instead as a command line shell (in a console window just like it would under the full GUI), but the registry setting you'd expect to be involved still says explorer.exe is the shell.

Comment: Woops, just noticed too late that I replied to a 3 year old comment.

Comment: Moreover, to someone who couldn't care less how µ$ messes up things.  Alle begin is moeilijk!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Of course I find another answer to this within minutes of posting.
https://serverfault.com/questions/1098102/how-to-start-cmd-as-default-shall-for-windows-server-core-2022

I was trying to remember how I accomplished this in the past so I could change my shell to pwsh instead of powershell when I found this question. It jogged my memory so I figure I would share.

I never found official documentation on this, but through experimentation on Server Core 2016 and Hyper-V Server 2019 I discovered that the String Value with the largest numeral `Name` in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\AlternateShells\AvailableShells` will run at login.
I did not extensively test the 'highest numeral' hypothesis, but observed that  my script stored in the Data of `60000` runs while `30000` does not. I also tested by adding a new String Value named `90000` with the data `notepad` and only notepad runs at login, not `60000` or `30000`.

Example:
[image: screenshot]

This change is immediate, so all you need to do is log off and back on to see the results.

Maybe I'll find this next time I forget how to do this :)

Answer (score -1):

I also saw the hklm shell= explorer.exe (the default windows shell), but expected cmd.exe for server core.
I did see whenever a user connects runonce.exe is runs (from startup folder) with a switch /AlternateShellStartup

However, how it knows to do that, is another question